# Is there a way to subset this dataset such that TCP, HTTP, DNS, etc becomes the column variables and the Info variable becomes the rows?

Tags: r

Can somebody help me out please? I need to spread the dataset such that TCP, HTTP etc will become columns and Info becomes the rows. I have tried **new_data<- spread(dataset, dataset$protocol, dataset$info)** and it didn't work. Please can someone help me out.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uorZS.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `tidyr::pivot_wider()`.

```
textFile <- "Protocol|Info
DNS|Standard query reponse 0x0800 AAA ppa.launchpad.net
TCP|35478 > 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0
TCP|80 > 42936 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=208 Win=30080
HTTP|HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
TCP|42936 > 80 [ACK] Seq=208, Ack=212 Win=30336 Len=0
HTTP|GET /ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease HTTP/1.1"

df <- read.csv(text = textFile,header = TRUE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
               sep = "|",row.names = NULL)
id <- 1:nrow(df)
df <- cbind(id,df)

library(tidyr)
df %>% pivot_wider(id_cols = id,
                   names_from = Protocol,
                   values_from = Info)
```

...and the output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
     id DNS                       TCP                     HTTP                    
  <int> <chr>                     <chr>                   <chr>                   
1     1 Standard query reponse 0… NA                      NA                      
2     2 NA                        35478 > 80 [SYN] Seq=0… NA                      
3     3 NA                        80 > 42936 [ACK] Seq=1… NA                      
4     4 NA                        NA                      HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modifi…
5     5 NA                        42936 > 80 [ACK] Seq=2… NA                      
6     6 NA                        NA                      GET /ubuntu/dists/xenia…
>
```

Note that since the example data does not document any relationship between the rows in the input file, I assigned an `id` column to ensure that a row in the original data frame is assigned to one and only one row of the wide format data frame.

Comment: Thanks @Len, I am grateful. However, the dataset has 192008 observations and 2 variables. How will I fit it into your textFile pattern (first part of your code?